# Merge linq results

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I got these 2 linq querys. Is there a easy way to merge these 2 querys. So when i'm using my dropdown's i can get a result if both return true??

```
public void CategorySort()
{
    var categoryId = int.Parse(ddlCat.SelectedValue);

    var data = new MyModelContext();

    var cat = from c in data.tblDocuments
              join sc in data.tblSubCategories on c.DocId equals sc.DocId
              where sc.CategoryId == categoryId
              select c;

    rptResult.DataSource = cat.ToList();
    rptResult.DataBind();
}

 public void SortPerson()
{
    var personId = int.Parse(ddlPerson.SelectedValue);
    var data = new MyModelContext();


    var documents = from d in data.tblDocuments
                    join sp in data.tblSubPersons on d.DocId equals sp.DocId
                    where sp.PersonId == personId
                    select d;

    rptResult.DataSource = documents.ToList();
    rptResult.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: is this EntityFramework? If so, what version?

Comment: havent used entity so far

Comment: What do you want done if one condition matches but the other does not?

Comment: if both values are true. then i want to return a result. if 1 value is false then a return "nothing is found" Would like the option too only use the one dropdown to search also

Answer (score 1):

Join to both and use `&&` operator to check both sub-records.

```
var cat = from c in data.tblDocuments
          join sc in data.tblSubCategories on c.DocId equals sc.DocId
          join sp in data.tblSubPersons on d.DocId equals sp.DocId
          where sc.CategoryId == categoryId && sp.PersonId == personId
          select c;
```

Comment: will this work if i would say ddlCat is empty and ddlPerson has an selected value?

Comment: No. If you want that requirement each expression to `(categoryId == null || sc.CategoryId == categoryId) && ...`. `int.Parse` will fail before that however, so you'll need to sort that out.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of how to find a document where it is either matched by category or subperson.

```
var cat = from c in data.tblDocuments
          join sc in data.tblSubCategories on c.DocId equals sc.DocId
          join sp in data.tblSubPersons on c.DocId equals sp.DocId
          where sc.CategoryId == categoryId || sp.PersonId == personId
          select c; //This needs to change to be what you want to select
```

Comment: will this work if i would say ddlCat is empty and ddlPerson has an selected value?

Comment: wont `int.parse(...)` fail if the list is empty?